# What is the regex for JavaScript's replace() to replace the second occurence of ":"?

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I want

```
file:///C:/Somepath/somefile.txt
```

to become

```
file:///C|/Somepath/somefile.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = 'file:///C:/Somepath/somefile.txt';
str = str.replace(/(:.*?):/, '$1|');
console.log(str); // Outputs "file:///C|/Somepath/somefile.txt"
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that that regex doesn't replace the second colon, per se, but rather, the second colon on the first line that includes at least two colons. (But since the OP's example string doesn't contain any newlines, that's probably fine.)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach is to write something like

```
s = s.replace(/^([^:]*:[^:]*):/, '$1|');
```

which replaces everything *up through* the second colon with itself, except changing that colon to a pipe.

Comment: With these regular expressions, all I see are smiley faces... `:P`